# Place a view over another view

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-toolbar

I have a custom toolbar in a separate file called `include_toolbar.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/include_toolbar"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

[image]

In a layout for an activity, I want to display this toolbar at the top, a camera preview view and an image button on top of that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/include_toolbar" />

    <com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView
        app:zxing_result_view="@color/zxing_custom_result_view"
        android:id="@+id/activity_scan_barcodeView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/activity_scan_flashlight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/activity_scan_barcodeView"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_flashOn"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

The `CompoundBarcodeView` is a component from [this](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded) library.

The problem with the `LinearLayout` is that the image button is not displayed.

If I change it to `RelativeLayout`, the image button is displayed but now the toolbar is gone.

[image]

How do I get both of them to display?

Comment: You didn't really say what exactly you tried to do with RelativeLayout.  That should be able to do what you want, if you know how to work it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make parent layout as a `LinearLayout` then make two child components one is toolbar and second is `RelativeLayout` and inside of that `RelativeLayout` put `CompoundBarcodeView` and `ImageButton`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/include_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView
            android:id="@+id/activity_scan_barcodeView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:zxing_result_view="@color/zxing_custom_result_view"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/activity_scan_flashlight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/activity_scan_barcodeView"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_flashOn" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

You may need to adjust Button's place in `RelativeLayout` according to your design.

Comment: And to avoid overdrawing, use a `RelativeLayout` only.

Comment: right we can use `layout_below` for `compoundBarcodeView` which can adjust it below toolbar and only one parent RelativeLayout will be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
<com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView
    app:zxing_result_view="@color/zxing_custom_result_view"
    android:id="@+id/activity_scan_barcodeView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView>

android:layout_height="match_parent" -> android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```